# Using Multiple Namespaces to Describe a Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I am writing code for a game, and wanted to include my main method in two different namespaces so that it could easily access all the classes from both the 'Engine' and 'Core' Namespaces.

```
namespace Engine Core
{
    class ExampleClass
    {
    }
}
```

Although I just put a space between Engine and Core, I know that this syntax is incorrect, I would like to know how to make a class a member of multiple namespaces. If this is not possible, is there anything that I could do that would act the same? (Classes in neither these two namespaces having to refer to this class by 'Engine.' or 'Core.'

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can split your class' definition by using the *partial* keyword (I know that's not what you're after), but how would having a class member of multiple namespaces work? Anyway, you could make ExampleClass not sealed, and extend it from another namespace under the same name. Like `public class ExampleClass : Engine.ExampleClass`

Answer (score 2):

A class can not belong to two different namespaces.
If you want to refer to a class of the Engine or Core namespaces without explicitly writing the namespace each time you reference a type of those namespaces, just use `using` at the beginning of the file. The using directive allows the use of types in a namespace so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace:

```
using Engine;
```

or

```
using Core;
```

Check the documentation: [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So you want someone to be able to access `ExampleClass` by using `Engine.ExampleClass` and `Core.ExampleClass`? I'm not sure why you would (I'm sure you have your reasons) but two ways to expose something like this are:

```
namespace Foo
{
    abstract class ExampleClass
    {
         //Only implement the class here
    }
}

namespace Engine
{
    class ExampleClass : Foo.ExampleClass
    {
         //Don't implement anything here (other than constructors to call base constructors)
    }
}

namespace Core
{
    class ExampleClass : Foo.ExampleClass
    {
         //Don't implement anything here (other than constructors to call base constructors)
    }
}
```

Or you could use namespace aliasing but every cs file using the class would require the alias to be defined.

```
using Engine = Core;
```